# Convert value ' ' to null in SQL or BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following extraction query

```
select A.documentid.Docid, A.documentId.Appid, A.timestamp, A.EventStatus, D.Sequence, D.EventAppName, E.Value as Federation

from `dbo.events` A left join `dam.eventsroot` B on A.documentid.docid = B.docid left join `dbo.documentroot` C on B.rootdocid=C.rootdocid 
inner join `dbo.reference_status` D

on A.DocumentID.AppID=D.EventAppID and A.EventStatus = D.EventStatus left join unnest(C.metadata) E on E.Key='Federation'

where A.timestamp > TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),DAY)
```

The result is that in column FEDERATION i get different values and values of '' (nothing) and i want to change them to Null.

How can i do this?

Thank you very much

Comment: `NULLIF(federation, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could use this in simple way like

```
  select A.documentid.Docid, A.documentId.Appid, A.timestamp, A.EventStatus, 
         D.Sequence, D.EventAppName, 
         Case 
          When LTrim(RTrim(E.Value)) = '' Then Null
          Else E.Value
          End AS Federation

  from dbo.events A 
  left join dam.eventsroot B         on A.documentid.docid = B.docid 
  left join dbo.documentroot C       on B.rootdocid=C.rootdocid 
  inner join dbo.reference_status D  on A.DocumentID.AppID=D.EventAppID and 
                                        A.EventStatus = D.EventStatus 
  left join unnest(C.metadata) E     on E.Key='Federation'

  where A.timestamp > TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

there are functions like `NULLIF(column , '')` and `REPLACE(column,'',NULL)` which you can them in such this cases. u can use `LTRIM(RTRIM(column))` so any extra spaces will be removed.
so like:

```
NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(federation)), '')
REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(federation)),'',NULL)
```

and so many other ways...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nullif()` in any database:

```
select nullif(federation, '')
```

You might want to remove white space in general, and do:

```
select nullif(trim(federation), '')
```

Or, perhaps:

```
select (case when trim(federation) <> '' then federation end)
```